# K8s -> nginx Ingress: SSO

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, single-sign-on, nginx-ingress

I have a service that has HTTP Basic Auth. In front of it  I have nginx Ingress, who also has basic-auth. How can I attach Authorization header with the credentials after Sign In with the Ingress, to achieve Single-Sign-On?

This is the configuration of my Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: Authentication Required
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: kibana-user-basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
  name: kibana-user
  namespace: {{.Release.Namespace}}
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: kibana-tls
    hosts:
    - {{.Values.ingress.user.host}}
  rules:
  - host: {{.Values.ingress.user.host}}
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kibana-logging
          servicePort: {{ .Values.kibana.service.internalPort }}
        path: /
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet:  proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;` to forward the `Authorization` header to the back end service.

The Ingress resource should looks like this

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: Authentication Required
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: kibana-user-basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: "proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;"
  name: kibana-user
  namespace: {{.Release.Namespace}}
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: kibana-tls
    hosts:
    - {{.Values.ingress.user.host}}
  rules:
  - host: {{.Values.ingress.user.host}}
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kibana-logging
          servicePort: {{ .Values.kibana.service.internalPort }}
        path: /
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can propagate Authorization header within `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers` [annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#external-authentication):

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: Authorization`

Or, alternative way you can achieve the same approach by applying `proxy_set_header` inside the target Ingress location via [configuration snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet) annotation as described [here](http://shairosenfeld.blogspot.com/2011/03/authorization-header-in-nginx-for.html):

```
annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic base64 encode value";
```

Comment: I think these annotation are used if you want your Ingress, to read the header from the query. But in my case the authentication is in the Ingress. I want to make the Ingress to propagate the authorization header to the backend service. In other words, when Ingress sends request to the backend service, i want the authorization header to be in this request

Comment: As per Nginx ingress documentation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers` annotation is used for passing Authorization header to backend services.